Error "failed to list the clusters" creating cloud serverless runtime template
I try to create a dataproc cloud serverless runtime template to get a spark environment notebook  in a vertex ai workbench instance.
If click on the "New Runtime Template" in category Dataproc Serverless Notebooks I get directly the error " failed to list the clusters" and i am not able to save the creation dialog.
What is the problem? Error makes not much sense because its a serverless thing. or?
[]
Thanks for help.
Best Regards
I tried to create a dataproc serverless notebook via vertex ai and I received the display error message. I don't know why.

sorry for that bad secreenshot. you can see here the details: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13AFcS0LKNWSODW-EviGnfIKPW6NBPYW_/view?usp=drive_link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H-Js_-Cbnh4WaKJCLYgeqfGdPs0IWixT/view?usp=drive_link
